# If the odds are $10:2$ against the next car you see being red, what percentage of cars in your area are red?

Tags: probability

So I had this question on a test and think I got it wrong, so I wrote it down.

> If the odds are $10:2$ against the next car you see being red, what percentage of cars in your area are red?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. What was your answer?

Comment: What did you say in your answer?

Comment: If you said $\sqrt2$, you were wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Odds are $10:2$ against you $\Rightarrow$ odds are $2:10$ in your favor. Out of $12$ experiments, $2$ are in your favor. Then the probability is $2/12 = 1/6$.

Answer (score 0):

This means that out of 12 possible outcomes, are that there will be 10 red cars and 2 of another kind of outcome.
So the percentage is 10/(10 + 2) = 5/6 = 0.833 = 83.3%

Comment: Be careful.  The odds are $10 : 2$ *against* the next car you see being red.